# Difference between “cozinheiro,” “chefe”, etc

Tags: significado, tradução-inglês, tradução, diferenças

I have encountered several different terms for a cook or chef, and I'm curious what the differences are when I should use each one.

Some terms I've seen:

> - chefe
> - cozinheiro
> - cozinheiro-chefe
> - chefe de cozinha

Comment: Only now do I realize that you've posted your question in English and I've answered in Portuguese.  I'm sorry. Will try to fix that when I have the time.

Comment: @Centaurus Se você quiser, mas eu entendi o resposta; entao, não se preocupe muito com isso

Comment: alumnus x alumni

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short *cozinheiro* means *cook* in general, whereas the other terms broadly mean *head cook*. Avoid *chefe* out of clear context though, as the word will likely be misunderstood for its widespread, unrelated, meaning of ‘head person, leader’. Let's go into the details now.

[***Cozinheiro*** (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/cozinheiro) is the standard Portuguese word for ‘cook’, related to [*cozinhar* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/cozinhar), ‘to cook’, and *cozinha*, ‘kitchen’. It is used both for professional cooks and anyone who can cook. So you can say of non-professional cooks things like:

> O pai é que é o cozinheiro lá em casa [dad is the one who cooks at home]
>
> Não sou mau cozinheiro [I’m not a bad cook]
>
> Ah! hoje tu é que és o cozinheiro [Ah! you are the cook today; you’re the one cooking today]

[***Chefe*** (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/chefe) generally means a person in a position of leadership or command, and is widely used in a variety of contexts: the person in charge of a group of workers, *chefe de estado* (head of state), *chefe de estação* (station master), *chefe da tribo* (chief of the tribe), *chefe do movimento* (the movement leader), and so on and so forth. [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/chefe) lists seven different leadership-related meanings for *chefe*, and Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) lists eleven. It can be used as an adjective too: *enfermeiro-chefe* (head nurse).

So ***chefe de cozinha*** or ***cozinheiro-chefe*** mean what the word combination suggests: a professional cook in charge of a team of cooks and kitchen assistants. For instance you find this short job description for [***cozinheiro-chefe*** at the Brazilian Ministry of Labour:](http://consulta.mte.gov.br/empregador/cbo/procuracbo/conteudo/tabela3.asp?gg=5&sg=3&gb=1)

> Organiza, coordena e controla o serviço de cozinha em restaurantes, hotéis, clubes, hospitais, indústrias e outros estabelecimentos do gênero, elaborando cardápios, orientando e verificando a execução das receitas e zelando pela ordem e higiene do local, para assegurar bom atendimento aos comensais.

[This article at InfoEscola describes ***chefe de cozinha***](http://www.infoescola.com/profissoes/chefe-de-cozinha/) in the same way.

***Chefe*** appears with the same meaning as *chefe de cozinha* and *cozinheiro chefe* in two Portugal-based online dictionaries: [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/chefe) and [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/chefe). It does not appear with any cooking-related meaning in Brazil-based [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/chefe) or [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=chefe); neither does it in Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) or Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (Lisboa, 2008). Houaiss does include the Gallicism *chef* though:

> grande cozinheiro encarregado da direção da cozinha de um restaurante, um hotel, uma residência, notáveis pela qualidade da alimentação

My feeling is that *chefe* in this sense is a recent adaptation of *chef*. I would be cautious about using it out of clear context, as it will be easily misunderstood, given the widespread use of *chefe* in its general meaning. So if asked what you do for a living you answer, “sou um chefe,” people will likely ask, “chefe de quê?” And if I hear someone saying, “o (meu) chefe é uma besta,” even if they’re dressed as a cook, I would think they were talking about their boss, most likely not a cook.

On a quick look around the web, it looks as though *chef* is used a lot more than *chefe* when used alone (i.e. not in *chefe de cozinha*): Google returned 360 occurrences of *chefs conceituados* against 191 *chefes conceituados* (and some of the latter may not relate to cooking). I’ve seen a couple of *chefe* used as a title for a cook though, as in [Chefe Silva](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chefe_Silva), a renowned Portuguese  cook.

I also get the feeling that *chefe* or *chef*, as often *chefe the cozinha*, places more emphasis on sophistication than *cozinheiro-chefe*. Even *chefe the cozinha* appears to be more recent than *cozinheiro-chefe* (it appears on Google Books in 1969 only, whereas *cozinheiro-chefe* can be found in abundance from the 1910s), so being more associated with the culture of celebrity cooks.

Comment: Como eu suspeitava, excelente trabalho de pesquisa Jacinto.

Answer (score 2):

> - [**chefe**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/chefe) - "cozinheiro principal que dirige um restaurante, geralmente conhecido pela boa cozinha."

O **"chefe"** (ou **"chef" em francês, mas também muito usado em pt-BR para não criar ambiguidade com os outros significados da palavra**) geralmente tem pelo menos 01 curso de gastronomia. Alguns chefes tem vários cursos inclusive em países cuja cozinha pretenderam conhecer a fundo, e aqueles conhecidos internacionalmente são profissionais muito bem pagos.

> - [**chefe de cozinha**](http://www.brasilprofissoes.com.br/profissao/chef-de-cozinha/) é o profissional responsável pela seleção dos ingredientes, pela preparação dos pratos, pela combinação dos sabores e pela sua apresentação. É de responsabilidade do chef de cozinha manter a ordem e a higiene na cozinha, além de coordenar seus auxiliares no preparo dos pratos. Esse profissional trabalha em conjunto com o gastrônomo, seguindo projetos de cardápio estabelecidos por ele e ajudando-o a relacionar aperitivos, pratos frios, principais, sobremesas e bebidas. Na ausência de um gastrônomo no estabelecimento, suas funções são realizadas pelo chef de cozinha.

**Chefe de cozinha** é o profissional que se ocupa do refinamento das refeições, sejam alimentos ou bebidas. **Assim como o "chef", é geralmente um profissional de nível superior.**

> - [**cozinheiro**](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cozinheiro+defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o) - indivíduo que cozinha, que sabe fazer pratos triviais ou refinados, esp. o que desenvolve profissionalmente esse conhecimento; mestre-cuca.

De um modo genérico, **"cozinheiro(a)" é a palavra usada para designar qualquer pessoa que cozinha e prepara pratos**. No gênero masculino, pode ser o cozinheiro de um regimento de cavalaria durante a guerra, um homem que mora só e cozinha para si próprio ou alguém que tem um pequeno restaurante e "faz de tudo" na cozinha.  **Em um grande estabelecimento onde existem vários profissionais, o cozinheiro é aquele que recebe ordens do cozinheiro chefe, descasca e corta os legumes, lava as verduras, separa os ingredientes, por fim, é aquele que tem "hands-on" a maior parte do tempo.**

> - [**cozinheiro ou chefe de cozinha?**](http://cozinhavibrante.com.br/chef-cozinheiro/) -  Quem estuda culinária, se forma cozinheiro. Quem estuda administração, se forma administrador. Ninguém estuda culinária e se forma chefe de cozinha, assim como ninguém estuda administração e se forma CEO. Chefe de cozinha, assim como CEO, são títulos que você obtém depois de muito esforço, experiência, dedicação e promoções ao longo da carreira.

"cozinheiro chefe" e "chefe de cozinha" são designações intercambiáveis.

Observem, contudo, que nem todos os estabelecimentos seguem a mesma nomenclatura ou tem todos os profissionais citados. Dependendo do que se tenha em termos de recursos humanos, as funções podem variar muito e podemos encontrar até um chef descascando batatas ou um único cozinheiro tomando todas as decisões.

Comment: Centaurus assim à primeira vista a mim parece-me que chefe, cozinheiro-chefe e chefe de cozinha são todos a mesma pessoa. São formas diferentes de se dizer.

Comment: Todas as denominações [Wikipedia][1]


  [1]: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef